# The block moves out

Tags: html, css

I am coding a site and but the block is moving out and the box-shadow does not work normally.To be precise, the block with the class 'sectionbg' does not fit into place.I tried to replace url () with colors and everything fell into place. That is, the problem is in the pictures themselves.
I tried placing the block in the center, setting all sizes in percentages did not help. I don't know how to solve this problem anymore! Help me please.
HTML:

```css
.background{
    background: url() no-repeat; /** blue**/
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
 }
 .gradientc{
    background: url() no-repeat;/** red**/
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 73.125%;
    height: 1772px;
    left: 13.4375%;
    top: 13.4375%;
    opacity: 0.95;
}
.sectionbg{
    background: url() no-repeat;/** green**/
    background-size: cover;
    width: 97%;
    height: 42.21218961625282%;
    margin-left: 2.8%;
    margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <header>    
    </header>
    <main >
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="gradientc">
            <div class="sectionbg">content text</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which block are you talking about?? It's not obvious from your question. Try to refactor your question :) and concentrate only on the problem without this images, backgrounds and so on. What do I see, your css is very messy:

1. First of all, using position absolute and float... Well, I don't know why should anyone do this. It's like you're going to the left and to the right at the same time.
2. Normally, the common practice to put an element in the center, it's {position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
3. If you really need an absolute positioning, then to put the element in the center you would use rather {position: absolute; left: 50%; transform-x: translate(-50%);}
4. If you're using left: and top: don't use right: and bottom: - either, or, not both at the same time
5. And be careful when using margin with absolutely positioned element

Try to start everything from beginning, delete all code, don't use position absolute unless you really know what do u use it for, and try to add as less code as possible to achieve your goal: if you see that you need to add this, but this ruines that and you need to add also this and this and you gain more conflicts with something that - it means you're doing something wrong.